# Perturbation Sums Question

Tags: combinatorics, summation

I'm taking a discrete structures class and I would appreciate some help with a homework problem. The problem is

> Attempt to find a closed form for the sum $\displaystyle \sum_{k=1}^n k^3$
>   by perturbation, only to find a closed form for the following sum $\displaystyle \sum_{k=1}^n k^2$.

I got as far as

> $\displaystyle S_n + (n+1)^3 =  a_0 + \sum_{k=1}^n (k+1)^3$

but now I am stuck. I don't undestand how to finish the problem and the teacher did not explain perturbation with sums very well. If somebody could explain it to me in greater detail and/or show me how to finish the problem I would really appreciate that.

Thanks

Comment: Are you using "Concrete Mathematics"?  This is the example given on page 44.  (The basic idea is to expand $(k+1)^3$ into $k^3+3k^2+3k+1$. (And I suspect that `perturbation-theory` is the wrong tag.)

Comment: No, I am not using that book. I am using "Combinatronics: Topics, Techniques, and Algorithims" and my book has nothing on perturbations. Could you explain how to do it or provide an image of the example?

Comment: Did you read the question?  The sum of $k^2$ is what you're trying to find.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You've got it started out:
$$S_n+(n+1)^3 = S_0 + \sum_{k=0}^n (k+1)^3.$$
We know that $S_0=0$, and we can expand $(k+1)^3$ by binomial coefficients (or by polynomial multiplication if you're bored), so we have that the right hand side is
$$\sum_{k=0}^n (k^3+3k^2+3k+3) = S_n + 3\sum_{k=0}^n k^2 + 3\sum_{k=0}^n k + \sum_{k=0}^n 1.$$

The $S_n$ terms will cancel, and we assume you know the sum of $k$ itself to get
$(n+1)^3 = 3\sum_{k=0}^n k^2 + n(n+1)/2 + n+1$, and from there you're doing some algebra.

Comment: Ah, ok. I see it a lot more clearly now. I'm going to work on it some more when I get home. Thanks for you help!

Answer (score 0):

I am not familiar with perturbation so cannot really help you.

However, maybe this can be useful anyhow:

$$\sum_{k=r}^{n}\binom{k}{r}=\binom{n+1}{r+1}$$
is a nice closed form that can be proved easily by induction. This for any nonnegative $r$.

Closed forms for: $$\sum_{k=1}^{n}k^{r}$$
can be deducted from it.

Comment: Unfortunatly, I have to specifically use perturbation to solve the problem. Thanks anyways though!